# How to convert a Vector to a comma-delimited String

Tags: blackberry, vector

I am using a vector in my BlackBerry app to hold email addresses, one string per address.  When I populate an EditField, I get output as : `[mahesh@gmail.com, ensisinfo15@gmail.com]`

I need output as : `mahesh@gmail.com, ensisinfo15@gmail.com`
This is because I need to assign these output values as a To address for an email.

---

here selected is one vector.

first class

```
obj.call(selected);
```

These vector element assigned in another vector in second class named as selected2

second class call event in first class

```
 public static BasicEditField toadd;

public void call(Vector selected2)
 {
selected = new Vector();
        selected.addElement(selected2);

            for(int i=0;i<selected.size();i++)
            {
                toadd.setText((String) selected.elementAt(i).toString());
}
}
```

Comment: please forward some suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the call() method you are expecting the selected vector to have two elements while in reality it has one.  The only element in selected is the vector selected2.  If you want to assign all the elements of selected2 to selected then you should loop through selected2 and put all of its elements in selected.  So the start of your method should look like this:

```
public void call(Vector selected2)
{
    Vector selected = new Vector();
    for(int i = 0; i < selected2.size(); i++)
    {
        selected.addElement(selected2.elementAt(i));
```

And then the rest of the method will proceed normally.

Comment: i am try this solution  one error is occured  class cast exception

Comment: Well none of the code I gave you should give a ClassCastException.  Debug your code and see which line it's coming from.  If you can't figure out why then ask a question here.